# NSArray Sort is not Integer Format 

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, sorting

i have a problem at NSArray Sorting

i use

```
NSArray *ratio = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"10",@"14",@"23",@"21",@"24",@"26",@"26",@"28",@"29",@"0",
                  @"-11",@"-22",@"-33",@"-44",@"-55",@"-66",
                  @"-77",@"-88",@"-99",@"-12",@"12",nil];
```

and i used

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self"  ascending: NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]];

NSLog(@"%@",[ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]]);
NSLog(@"Biggest : %@", [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Smallest : %@", [sortedArray lastObject]);
```

but can not sort like integer:( sorted string format  looks like following ;
9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 43, 4, 4, 31, 30, 29, 29, 28, 28, 27, 27)

i tried that code but  gives error :(
 NSArray *sortedArray = [ratio sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString * str1, NSString * str2) {

```
    if ([str1 integerValue] < [str2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([str1 integerValue] > [str2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
   return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Error says; incompatible block pointer types initializing  ..... expected NSComparator

Comment: add object as NSNumber to the array instead of NSString format

Answer (score 4):

This works perfectly:

```
NSArray *sortedArray2 = [ratio sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id str1, id str2) {

    if ([str1 integerValue] < [str2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([str1 integerValue] > [str2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSLog(@"%@",[ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]]);
NSLog(@"Biggest : %@", [sortedArray2 objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Smallest : %@", [sortedArray2 lastObject]);
```

Comment: Gives error my friend :(: Incompatible block pointer types initializing

Comment: @coexploit:  it's because the types of the parameters should be `id` not `NSString*`

Comment: check now, but it works for me quite well and previous version

Comment: @Nekto: it should have been giving you compiler warnings before.  Make sure you are compiling with `-Wall` set.

Comment: Just to note: Your example works perfectly, only it sorts in descending order, switch < and > in the 'if' conditions to change the sort order :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `@"intValue"` as the key in place of `@"self"` in the sort descriptor.

Comment: @coexploit:  in place of `@self` in the sort descriptor.